# CGPointMake in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, cgpoint

How to use `CGPointMake` in `Swift`? Is there an equivalent for it? I am getting an error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'CGPointMake'

Basically, I am trying to assign a position to a Sprite Kit node and cannot figure out how to do it in Swift.

```
class PlayerSpaceship: Spaceship {

    func launchMissile() {

        var missile = Missile.playerMissile()

        // This line gives above mentioned error.    
        missile.position = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) 
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to compile `var p = CGPointMake(0, 0)` in Swift just fine.  Is it possible that you just haven't included the CoreGraphics framework?

Comment: I'm pretty sure CGPointMake only exists because NeXTSTEP came out before C99: `(CGPoint){0.0,0.0}`

Comment: @AaronGolden, thanks. Indeed, adding `import CoreGraphics` solved the issue.

Comment: Did @sjeohp's suggestion of using `CGPoint(x:0, y:0)` fix the problem *without* importing CoreGraphics or is there some other reason you accepted that answer?

Comment: There are not real missiles I hope?! :-)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use `CGPoint(x: Float, y: Float)`

Answer (score 11):

You call it a little differently, without the make.

```
CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20)
```

Answer (score 6):

Xcode 6.3.1 shows 4 different Swift initializers for CGPoint. They are:

```
CGPoint()
CGPoint(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)
CGPoint(x: Double, y: Double)
CGPoint(x: Int, y: Int)
```

Answer (score 4):

In the code it should looks like this (Xcode 6.1):

```
let point: CGPoint = CGPoint(x:10,y:10)
```

Comment: `let point = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)` should be enough in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Or also, you can use **CGFloat** type for CGPoint

```
 CGPoint(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)
```