# CGPointMake in swift or CGPoint

Tags: swift

I want to move an UIImageView, I already did  this in Objective-C and it completely worked.
This was the code:

```
tank.center = CGPointMake(tank.center.x + TankX, tank.center.y + TankY);
```

`TankX` is set in viewDidLoad to 2 and `TankY` is set to 0. So the tank moves to the right.
But when i want to do this in Swift it doesn't work. 
Swift code:

```
tank.center = CGPointMake(tank.center.x + TankX, tank.center.y + TankY)
```

I also tried CGPoint but I also can't get it working.
I already saw this question: [CGPointMake in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070408/cgpointmake-in-swift) but I couldn't manage to use it.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Edit: Error: Could not find an overload for '+' that accepts the supplied arguments

Comment: I edited my question the CGPointMake code gives an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try this:

```
tank.center = CGPoint(x: tank.center.x + CGFloat(TankX), y: tank.center.y + CGFloat(TankY))
```

It converts TankX and TankY to CGFloats so they can be added to other CGFloats.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for, works perfectly! Thank you very much:-)

Comment: CGPointMake is deprecated in swift because it has structure initializers which do the same thing, jus as succinctly.  The same is true of the other ...Make... functions as well.

Answer (score 1):

`tank.center.x` and `TankX` probably don't have the same type. Remember in Swift there is no implicity conversion between Int/Float/Double. You have to cast them explicitly, like: `x = Double(y)`

Comment: Their type is both float

Comment: If `tank.center` is `CGPoint`, `tank.center.x` would be `CGFloat`, which is the same as `Double`